# why is my android Application crash?

Tags: android

Why on my phone the aplication is working but in on my tablet it crashes ?

**xml code:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/shaam" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/note" />
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >
</GridLayout>
```

**java code:**

```
Button[][] board_button = new Button[3][1];
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    crate_board();
}
public void crate_board(){
    GridLayout gridLayout1 = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.gridLayout2);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point screenSize = new Point();
    display.getSize(screenSize);    
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++){
            board_button[i][j] = new Button(this);  
            LayoutParams xxx = new LayoutParams(screenSize.x/3-(10*2), screenSize.x/3-(10*2)) ;
            board_button[i][j].setLayoutParams(xxx);
            board_button[i][j].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.x);
            gridLayout1.addView(board_button[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

**in my phone:**

[image]

**in my tablet:**

[image]

when i change the code to:

```
Button[][] board_button = new Button[3][4];
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    crate_board();
}
public void crate_board(){
    GridLayout gridLayout1 = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.gridLayout2);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point screenSize = new Point();
    display.getSize(screenSize);    
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++){
            board_button[i][j] = new Button(this);  
            //LayoutParams xxx = new LayoutParams(screenSize.x/3-(10*2), screenSize.x/3-(10*2)) ;
            //board_button[i][j].setLayoutParams(xxx);
            board_button[i][j].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.x);
            gridLayout1.addView(board_button[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

the app working!

phone:

[image]
tablet:

[image]

how can i fix the problem?

.......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Specify the logcat output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Are there multiple `layout` folders defined - such as `layout-large`, `layout-xlarge`? If so, check if `activity_main.xml` is defined appropriately in all folders.

Comment: How can i write:                                                                              LayoutParams xxx = new LayoutParams(screenSize.x/3-(10*2), screenSize.x/3-(10*2)) ;
board_button[i][j].setLayoutParams(xxx);                                 in xml code?