# How can i write this code in xml?

Tags: android

How can i write this code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point screenSize = new Point();
    display.getSize(screenSize);
    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(screenSize.x/3-(10*2), screenSize.x/3-(10*2));
    button1.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

in xml?

Comment: u can write dimen in value folders

Comment: show us what have you tried..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147508/why-is-my-android-application-crash